# Is there a way to get a stored procedure signature?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Let's say we have an Oracle procedure:

```
procedure proc(i_value in number, o_value out varchar2) is
begin 
    null;
end proc;
```

The output values which are passed to the `callproc()` function should be initiated by one of the Oracle types (`cx_Oracle.NUMBER`, `cx_Oracle.STRING` etc.).

In our case a variable, say named `out_value`, would receive `o_value` from the procedure and before being passed should be defined like this:

```
out_value = cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
```

It is OK if we know the signature of the procedure. But what if not?

Is there a way to get types of the output values of a procedure before calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to query the 'data dictionary' views like USER_PROCEDURES and USER_ARGUMENTS.  There is no built-in 'describe PL/SQL' API in cx_Oracle.